# Safari CSS Problem / Background image

Tags: html, css, image, safari, fullscreen

I have a full screen background image, which keeps the aspect ratio and works in all browsers fine but not in Safari. I'm good at CSS but at this point I don't know exactly what the problem is. It seems that Safari has a problem keeping the vertical center and creates gaps at the top and bottom:

```
<div id="bg">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="loading"><img src="images/home.jpg" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,#bg,#bg table,#bg td {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative
    }

#bg div{
    position:absolute;
    width:200%;
    height:200%;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%
    }

#bg td{
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center
    }

#bg img{
    min-height:50%;
    min-width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: table
    }
```

Any CSS <strike>cr</strike>hacks here?

Comment: Make sure you have the "body" and "html" margin and padding reset to 0 in your css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use an actual image as a background instead of a background image in your CSS, a JavaScript solution might be better suited for your needs as it doesn't introduce extraneous markup into your design.

Check out jQueryMaxImage: http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/ and here's one that I wrote, jquery.FullScreenBG: https://github.com/huntedsnark/jquery.fullScreenBG

If you don't want to do it with a script there is a way to do it using CSS# plus non-standard CSS for compatability:

```
html {
    background: url(images/yourImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

    /* CSS3 */
    background-size: cover;

    /*other browser specific */
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

    /* non-standard for IE */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.yourImage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='yourImage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"
}
```

You really should not be adding all kinds of table markup for the sake of a background image.